# Re-broadcasting 24/7 stream with FFMPEG, using HLS. Original stream resets (probably), ffmpeg produces no HLS

Tags: ffmpeg

I am rebroadcasting a live `mp3` stream (probably it is using `icecast` - the admin requested me to re-broadcast it on another server). I am using `ffmpeg` for this task, using `HLS` playlist, to a public `URL` location.

It works! But sometimes (I mean once per day, mostly in the night), the `m3u8` playlist file disappears or the re-broadcast is not working and I need to kill the ffmpeg process on the server and start it again.

```
ffmpeg -y -i "THE URL OF LIVE MP3" -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 4 playlist.m3u8
```

I think there could be a problem with the original stream. But even if that happens, I need ffmpeg to "reload" the url of the stream. Is there any method to check and reset ffmpeg automatically?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add reconnection flags. If issue is with input it can help:

```
ffmpeg \
-reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2 \
-y -i "THE URL OF LIVE MP3" -f hls -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 4 playlist.m3u8
```